# Delete Stores in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, category, store-view, stores, store-id

I have a Magento Site which have around 20 stores.

I have deleted 17 stores as they are not useful to me but when I go to Admin panel and go `Catalog -> Categories` then it shows me the following error

`Requested store is not found`

Update:

[image]
Give any suggestions on it.

[image]

Comment: check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

**Try Below Command :-**

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `store_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

**Clear Cache and Check**

---

change **155 line** of `Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager`:

**From :-**

```
if (null === $this->currentStoreId) {
```

**To :-**

```
if (!$this->currentStoreId) {
```

[Reference Link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11453)

Comment: Thanks for your Quick Response

No row is changed.
`Query executed OK, 0 rows affected`

Comment: I think `store_id=0` is for All store

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HT7C.png Is This Type Of Error ??

Comment: 1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): Requested store is not found

Comment: Still Got no success same error .

Answer (score 0):

I guess your admin session still has a filter for the store that you deleted in the category view.

Does a logout / login solve the problem?

If not, go to your database into the table `ui_bookmark`.

There, filter `user_id` for your admin-user-id and check if there's an entry for the category view. Simply delete it.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

I Have check my ui_bookmark table but there is no entry regarding category view.
Instead it has 2 entries for namespace category_listing.

Comment: Delete the one where `current`=1

Comment: current is 0 as i have attached a screenshot in my question .

Comment: I can see that current is 1 for the upper one. You can also delete both, it doesn't matter. Magento will create new ones.

Comment: Still facing the same issue I have deleted both , and they didn't create new ones.

Comment: have you flushed cache, logged out, logged in?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102154/discussion-between-urocks-and-simonthesorcerer).

Answer (score 0):

At line no 164 add the below code of Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager:

if(!$storeId){
    if(isset($_COOKIE['store']) && $_COOKIE['store'] !== ''){
        $storeId = $_COOKIE['store'];
    } else {
        $storeId = $this->getDefaultStoreView()->getCode();
    }
}

And then, change line no 155 of Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager

=> FROM :

if (null === $this->currentStoreId) { => To :

if (null === $this->currentStoreId || '' === $this->currentStoreId) {